# Connection Refused on maven compile

Tags: java, maven, wsdl, jaxb2

I'm getting an exception (`java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect.`) when trying to compile a maven project using the jaxb2 plugin to generate the class by a wsdl provided by a url.

However, I can get this wsdl when get it by a browser.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the browser using a proxy which maven is not aware about?

Comment: I setted the proxy in settings.xml in my .m2 directory.

Comment: Is the WSDL hosted on a Windows machine?  Is the URL using the correct name for the host?

Comment: You need to tell the jaxb2 plugin about the proxy too.  T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions on how to setup a proxy in jaxb2: https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Configuring-Proxies/c32d4e2af4ab9c1fd5b3d67fb559ec32affab745

I just put `<useActiveProxyAsHttpproxy>true</useActiveProxyAsHttpproxy>` in my `configuration` tag of plugin.

Also, I prev set the proxy on my maven settings.xml

Answer (score 2):

While you might be able to resolve the connection issues given the comments above, the error message shows a fundamental problem in your build. If your maven build downloads the WSDL each time it compiles, you don't have repeatable builds, as the WSDL can change each time it's accessed. While it might be convenient to alway load the latest WSDL, I'd recommend downloading the WSDL and add it to your src tree. Then your build will not break, if the WSDL changes. You need to take take, however, to manually update the WSDL if you want to support a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error in a java project built with maven and. On compilation the plugin tries to get some sources on the net and my company had set up a proxy. So you have to configure correctly your `settings.xml` and add

```
<useActiveProxyAsHttpproxy>true</useActiveProxyAsHttpproxy>
```

to the configuration tag of the plugin causing the error in the `pom.xml`